# Add values from one table to another

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL: TableA and TableB

```
TableA                                 TableB
col1 col2 col3 clo4                    col1 col2
---- ---- ---- ----                    ---- ----
A     N    W                           A     122
B     Q    E                           C     311
C          R                           
D     H    T
```

col4 in TableA is empty, Is there any way to add values of col4 in TableB to the col4 in Table A where col1 values in TableA = col1 in TableB? So that the result will be something like:

```
col1 col2 col3 clo4                    
---- ---- ---- ----                    
A     N    W     122                        
B     Q    E     NULL                     
C          R     311                      
D     H    T     NULL
```

Comment: I want to use UPDATE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the [UPDATE...FROM variant of UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html), something like this:

```
update tablea
set clo4 = tableb.col2
from tableb
where tablea.col1 = tableb.col1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/eef82/2